# Rhodes before_filter for controllers 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter, rhodes

Does Rhodes has before_filter for controllers similar to Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no support for `before_filter` or `after_filter`.

However, it is on their radar, and [there is a story](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/7158885) on their public Pivotal Tracker page for it, if you want to keep tabs on that particular story.